# Where can I ask about what are the key principles every programmer should have?

Tags: discussion, support

It has been a long time ago I developed something. But when I'm coding I really don't know if I code according to the principles. For example I want to create ASP.NET MVC app I jump from creating the Models, Controller. Jump into CSS, change HTML. Do the testing. In an unchronic way. And this makes me feel like I'm a low profile programmer. Now I need to know is there something available that can help me becoming better at programming. And to which principles I should spend more time and that I should apply?

Comment: A good book on the basic principles of whatever you're doing - one that gets praise from the community; Amazon.com reviews are a good pointer as well - would probably be the best first step

Comment: e.g. http://www.asp.net/mvc/books/aspnet-mvc-1-books

Comment: Nowhere at Stack Exchange I'm afraid.
["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score 4):

There is nowhere on the SE network that such a question would be on-topic. With the exception of Software Recommendations (where there are very specific requirements), requests for off-site resources are off-topic on all of the programming-based SE sites. The rest of it is much too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly enough, such questions are legitimate (you want to improve your skills), and there are in SO community people that could give you nice advices.

But those questions also tend to attract many low quality answers

- just use xyzz dev environment it will do everything for you
- phew, xyzz is bad **MY** prefered one is ztxx
- stupid you, real programmers only use yyzx

and signal/noise ratio soon goes to 0  :-(

SE sites choice is to concentrate on Q&A, meaning precise questions that could get short answers will little room if any to debate.

In my opinion, it is a pity that we cannot find a place to build a high quality summary of best practices, but it is explicitely off topic here. And main reason for that is just above ...