# What about standards?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, scope

I have a problem(s). I end up using SO and staying with a lot of questions (some good, some bad) about standards. I feel that their place is not exactly in SO, as it sometimes can be subjective on languages or tools that do not have something set in stone (I.E C# region, for instance).

But I feel that SO is the best place to ask such questions because of the amount of programmers and content providers that the site have available to provide an answer.

Also, I don't feel confident anymore posting in other places of the web such questions.

What to do in those cases? Should I make these questions? If so, how can I make a good question for this type of topic?

Edit: To clarify, I'm not asking where on the SE network I can make such question, [opposed to this question](http://With%20all%20these%20points%20in%20mind,%20is%20there,%20or%20could%20be%20there,%20a%20place%20to%20ask%20open-ended%20questions?). I'm asking on wheter or not such questions are legitimate (already answered here, thanks!), and if it was, how to make good questions on these topics.

Comment: Maybe give us an example question?

Comment: @TinyGiant Right! For instance, I wanted to ask about Inline CSS and scripts - I do not use neither, but some folks on my team does. I see questions such as this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389808/using-inline-css-a-no-no-or-okay-in-certain-situations But I do not see any hard sources on the matter, just opinions... So I end up with no good arguments on the matter, besides opinions.

Comment: Oh, these are not *standards*, they're *personal opinions*. Standards are different beasts entirely.

Comment: I would classify that as a general guideline. There is *guidance* available across the internet on that regard. That is not a standards question. Standards are by definition a defined set of rules, guidelines a just a set of general opinions that might possibly be shared by a group of people.

Comment: see also: [Where can I ask about what are the key principles every programmer should have?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299651/where-can-i-ask-about-what-are-the-key-principles-every-programmer-should-have)

Comment: @gnat thank you for the links provided. I took a note of those and made a edit.

Comment: @TinyGiant thank you. Yes, guidance is a goodwording for that. My main problem is that english is not my native language, so I make lots of associations and assumptions to try to understand and communicate here. My main topic was to include both - guidelines and standarts (if there is no standards to the topic, what are the guidelines? - for example.) I just wanted to clarify, and, if I could, help on how to achieve better questions on these types.

Comment: Your question would still be off-topic because it would basically be "If there is a fact based answer give me that, if not then give me your opinion", what you could ask is something like "Is there a standard for this? If so what is it?"

Comment: @TinyGiant yes, I know, I just gave a example. I'm not discussing that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi exactly. That's why I'm asking about standards, not opinions. I linked to a question as a example why I cannot use that as a argument point, because it's just a opinion. I asked about the possibility to ask about standarts to have hard data on discussions. Understood?

Comment: @Malavos, dunno. By *standards*, do you mean things like *the C++ standard* and *the Common LISP standard*, or things like *should I put my styles in external resources* and *should I indent by three spaces instead of half a tab*?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Your first statement. Like the C++ standard. I want to know if, at my example, if there's a norm for when to use inline CSS and Javascript, not a recomendation for it, not opinions on when to use it.

IAm I not being clear enough? Can you help editing the question to make it more clear?

Comment: Okay, let's look at this another way. There are specs for HTML, CSS and Javascript, that actually *specify* JS and CSS can be used either inline or from external resources. Standards, first sense, stop there. They don't care how you use what they specify, they just specify. "Inline vs. external CSS/JS" is a matter of coding conventions, not standards (unless you're referring to "company standards", which only are coding conventions rationalized and enforced across a specific community of developers).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes. In that example, then, the question would receive answers that indicate that the specs do not specify if the scripting or css should be inline or not - they just specify that it CAN be used inline or external scripts. So, in this case, would this question be on-topic and "doable" by SO policy? Please understand that I'm not asking for neither personal conventions or private standards. And thank you very much for the help. this debate is helping quite a lot to translate what I want, and making me understand the problem, policy and wording.

Comment: Unfortunately, in that example, the question would not be answered like that (hopefully), but would be closed as primarily opinion-based instead. Servy's answer does apply here, and such a question would be off-topic on Stack Overflow. Anyway, thank you for your efforts in meta-asking before asking, these do not go unnoticed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I understand now. I will not make these type of questions then, and will proceed with Servy guidance.

Comment: The only thing I disagree with this discussion here is the duplicate mark - The pointed question has a answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe Which is "With all these points in mind, is there, or could be there, a place to ask open-ended questions?" Which is not my question. Flags should be more precise overrall..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that SO is as useful of a site as it is, and the reason you can find so much quality content here is precisely because questions like these *aren't* welcome.  When you remove the site's quality standards for questions then it will devolve into a site as useful as all of the sites you're refusing to participate in.

Comment: Servy, thanks for the answer ,+1, but to clarify - considering that nowadays technical forums are a big letdown, and SO is centering the content quite nicely, where to ask these questions then? Nowhere? Could you edit and include on what I should do in these cases?

Comment: @Malavos They're not on topic anywhere on SE.  Beyond that you'll have to try to figure out for yourself where you want to ask it.  I can tell you that you're going to be hard pressed to find another site outside of SE that wouldn't welcome such questions, so you can ask it just about wherever else you want to.

Comment: ... though indiscriminate welcome to questions like that probably has the expected result on possible answers/comments there too. Which is why you didn't want to go there from the start. ;-)